# Python smtplib email does not send even without error

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am trying to send a small simple email with a message of just a string. This string will look something like 'The GB vs DEN game just ended at {some time} '.

My function is as below:

```
def send_email(msg,address):
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',port,context=context) as server:
                print('Sending Email')
                server.login(user,password)
                try:
                        server.sendmail(user,address,msg)
                        print('Email Sent!')
                except:
                        print('Message Sending Failed')
```

I know that this works because using it elsewhere in my program works. The only difference between the times I use it is the message.

The context that I am using it in is this.

```
 if played_status == 'COMPLETED' or played_status == 'FINAL' or played_status == 'POSTGAME-REVIEWING':
                    message = 'The {} vs {} game just ended at {}.'.format(away_team,home_team,time.asctime())
                    send_email(message, receiver)
                    print(message)
```

When this code segment executes the output is as follows:

```
Sending Email
Email Sent!
The GB vs DEN game just ended at Sun Dec  7 01:19:10 2019.
```

Based on this output, the email should have sent correct? Is there a better way I can figure out why this isn't working?

EDIT: After adding a print statement to display sendmail return code, this is my code.

```
def send_email(msg,address):
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',port,context=context) as server:
                print('Sending Email')
                print(server.login(user,password))
                try:
                        server.sendmail(user,address,msg)
                        print('Email Sent!')
                except:
                        print('Message Sending Failed')
```

And this is the return value printed. According to what I've found online that means it was successful?

```
The WAS vs GB game just ended at Sun Dec  8 12:59:23 2019.
Sending Email
(235, b'2.7.0 Accepted')
Email Sent!
```

Comment: BTW: currently Gmail has more restricted system and every application needs own password to access mailbox. See [Allow less secure apps to access your Gmail account](https://devanswers.co/allow-less-secure-apps-access-gmail-account/) and [How to Create an App Password for Gmail](https://devanswers.co/create-application-specific-password-gmail/)